# Draw sequential rectangles of varying width

Tags: d3.js

Simply trying to draw 4 rectangles of varying width, side-by-side (they will alternate colors). I want the x attribute to be the d[i-1] + d[i-1] + d[i-1].attr('width'). I will eventually scale the widths, but cannot figure out how to get the x values (+ the width) of the *previous* rectangle

```
  const svg = d3.create("svg")
    .attr("width",300)
    .attr('height',300)
  const bb = [15,75,150,235]

var g = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(bb)
  .enter().append("g")
  .classed('rect', true)

  g.append('rect')
  .attr('x',(d,i) => bb[i-1] + bb[i-1] + bb[i-1].attr('width'))
  .attr('y',100)
  .attr('height',120)
  .attr('width',d => d)
  .attr('stroke','none')
  .attr('fill',function(d,i){ if(i % 2){return 'gray'}else{return 'blue'}})
```

Answer (score -1):

Relevant code accomplishes this:

```
  g.append('rect')
  .attr('x',(d,i) => d3.sum(bb.slice(0,i)))
  .attr('y',100)
  .attr('height',120)
  .attr('width',d => d)
  .attr('stroke','none')
  .attr('fill',function(d,i){ if(i % 2){return 'gray'}else{return 'blue'}})
```